# Access Personal Workspace through CMIS

Tags: nuxeo

I am using `Nuxeo` as multi tenant system and want to access my personal workspace through `CMIS` query. So, please help me with the query to access the same.

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: Also please don't cross-post with answers.nuxeo.com https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/25873aa9f2b04799b845d91c9139127f/Access-Personal-Workspace-through-CMIS